# Does any JPA implementations support write-behind caching?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, ehcache

Am I correct in saying Hibernate 3.6.5 does not support write-behind caching (implemented by EhCache 2.4.2)?

Are there any other JPA compliant ORM that supports write-behind caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/3368.page) forum thread, the answer is no (as it requires code changes in hibernate). EclipseLink however supports write-behind caching strategy using Coherence (there is a good intro article [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/high-performance-jpa-glassfish-0)).